Why are US federal statutes consolidated as an inconsistent mix of "Positive Law" and "Non-Positive Law"?
When it comes to consolidated acts, basically every other government would regularly publish an alphabetized compilation consisting of the most up-to-date version of each act in force at that time. So for example, if one wanted to view the most up-to-date version of the UK Highways Act 1980 or the Canada Criminal Code, the consolidation would just be that act with any amendments applied. However, for some reason it's much more complicated with US federal law.
Of the (currently) 54 titles of the US Code (USC), some areas of law have been codified as what the Office of Law Revision Counsel calls "Positive Law",[1] meaning that the title is a proper statute in itself. However the other "Non-Positive Law" titles aren't really statutes but rather "prima facie evidence of the law". Those titles consist of every act in its category combined and editorialized to make a quasi-official legal code. The USC tends to make minor changes from what Congress passed, ranging from "Titles" in the act changed to "Subchapters" in the USC codification, to some sections having their wording simplified.[2] This means that the Non-Positive sections can sometimes be unreliable since the wording of the actual law is different from the USC. Also the numbering is often clunky due to acts being squeezed as chapters in-between other chapters.[3]
This makes US federal law rather awkward, since the consolidated versions of many acts are inelegantly organized and divided, and sometimes sections are different from the actual text of the law. With that established, why was US federal law codified like this?
[1] such as Title 17 - Copyright, Title 11 - Bankruptcy, and Title 49 - Transportation
[2] such as 47 USC s. 152, coming from the Federal Communications Act of 1934
[3] such as the Religious Freedom Restoration Act of 1993 being codified as 42 USC ss. 2000bb to 2000bb-4

History and politics
The US is alone among common law jurisdictions in creating a government curated and partially (mostly) definitive consolidated code of laws. Given the time at which this initiative started, late 19th century, and the time at which it actually happened, 1934, this was unbelievably innovative.
Because, it was a real problem.
The 19th century was a time of unbelievably rapid change which necessitated a massive ramp up in lawmaking all over the world. Before this, legislative law was a relatively tiny proportion of “the law”, legislatures really didn’t make a lot of new law.
As more and more Acts were being pumped out each year, the law that affected any given aspect of life might be scattered across half a dozen or more pieces of primary legislation.
The general response was for private publishers, the ones who published case reports usually, to start publishing consolidated “codes” for their jurisdiction. Of course, these had no official status.
The USA decided that it should look to the way they did these things in civil law jurisdictions like France and said “what a good idea”. The English of course, said “we can’t learn anything from foreigners”. The USA and the English had had, shall we say, different historical experiences with France.
So, kudos to the US for seeing the problem and trying to solve it. However, solving the problem creates another problem - in a common law jurisdiction, the laws passed by the legislature is the law: so, what status, if any, should be given to a government produced consolidated code? Well, you periodically put a law before Congress to make the code the law.
Awesome. But that still leaves two problems. Congress doesn’t stop passing laws (I mean, after 250 years you’d have thought they’d have gotten them right by now), so there’s a lag between that happening and the annual update to the code. And, there’s a delay between the annual updates and the 5-yearly laws that actually update the code. So, that.
How was this dealt with in other common law jurisdictions? Largely, it wasn’t.
Laws continued to be scattered across multiple acts and lawyers relied on private consolidations on a trust but verify basis. Occasionally, legislatures on their own initiative would create consolidated Acts for big ticket items like criminal law, real estate law etc. When they did, that tended to create a bit of internal discipline- when they passed a new act that affected, say, real estate, they’d use it to amend the real estate act rather than creating isolated provisions. Incidentally, a discipline that the US Congress didn’t need because they could rely on the code to deal with ‘omnibus’ acts.
Then, computers and, way more importantly, the internet. Absolute game changer. All the laws, all together. Private publishers go out of business unless they provide value add like commentary or cross-reference to case law.
Don’t judge the US or the rest of the world by what you see today.

IIUC, you say that the "government" (meaning the executive here) publishes "collections" (a consolidated code), if you want, of law that was originally passed, as it should be, by the legislature. (Funny that you say "in a common law jurisdiction, the laws passed by the legislature is the law": That is very much the case in civil law jurisdictions as well, isn't it? Lawmaking being the second core privilege and duty of the legislature, after passing a budget.) And do I understand correctly that the executive then lets the legislative "pass" that collection? (ctd.)

... What about the scattered single laws the consolidated Acts contain? Are they superseded?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica but in civil law jurisdictions the legislature amends the code - they don’t pass stand alone Acts.

@DaleM Well, that depends, I think. There are a number of "main laws" governing broad areas like "civil" (contracts, family, liability) and criminal law; in Germany these are "books", like BGB and the StGB, probably similar to the consolidated codes in the U.S. Those are amended. But then you also have special laws, like the recent "Gesetz zur Ermöglichung hybrider und virtueller Mitgliederversammlungen im Vereinsrecht", making virtual meetings of registered clubs valid. Those may be comparable to standalone "acts".

But my questions remain: Am I understanding the legislative process correctly, and are the standalone Acts "collected" in the consolidated code superseded?

This doesn't really answer the question of why some of the titles of the USC haven't been made positive law yet. For all I know, the answer might be as simple as "Congress hasn't had time to review those titles yet", but I think there should be some attempt at answering it.

In terms of "other common law jurisdictions", in Canada they would (somewhat) regularly publish an official "revised statutes" book which would have each Act of Parliament consolidated and alphabetized in it. Of course this stopped once the internet became common as they could just apply amendments to the online version as they're passed. It seems like that was a far more straightforward method than what the US did.

@Brian specifically addressed in the paragraph starting with “Awesome”

I think that this is not clear about whether the titles that are not positive law were created after Congress made other titles positive law, or whether they're just not positive law because they've been updated since they were made positive law. If it's the latter, it raises the question of why Congress has not adopted a practice of consistently amending the USC to avoid this problem---something that the answer claims does not even require that much "discipline".

The United States Office of Law Revision Counsel explains:

Laws are initially passed as statutes of Congress, published as "Public Laws"
While a non-"positive" title in the US Code is helpful, as evidence of the statutes it contains, it is not a literal Act of Congress.
Laws are sometimes inconsistent or duplicative and may contain ambiguities. Positive law codification resolves inconsistent laws, eliminates duplicate provisions, and clarifies ambiguities.
Codification into a positive title, for fresh enactment by Congress, takes time. "The Office actively seeks input from Federal agencies, congressional committees, experts in the area of law being codified, and other interested persons. That input is essential in ensuring that the laws are restated correctly and in identifying obsolete, ambiguous, or inconsistent provisions and reaching a consensus on how those provisions should be handled. Because much research, consultations, and consensus-building are essential in correctly restating the laws, the process of positive law codification is inherently time consuming."
There are currently 27 positive-law titles in the Code. Work continues on others.

canada
The US is not alone in having its legislature enact fresh, official aggregations of its laws. Canada and its provinces do this as well. Canada enacted a nearly complete, "Revised" statute book in 1886, 1906, 1927, 1952, 1970, and 1985. These projects took years each. Granted, these are based on chapters that are each a consolidation of a single Act of Parliament and its subsequent amendments, so somewhat simpler than the US Code project(s).

I'm aware of the "revised statutes" system in Canada, as mentioned in the opening.
The difference between the USC and RSC (and RSO, RSBC, etc) is that each chapter of a Canadian revised statutes volume is a consolidated Act of Parliament, whereas the USC has some titles as proper statutes (positive law) and others as prima facie editorialized compilations (non-positive law) which often differ from the statutes-at-large that they derive from.


why was US federal law codified like this?

Because Congress has enacted only some titles of the US Code as such.  The code arose originally from private efforts at codifying federal statutes; the official codification was adopted in the 1920s if Wikipedia is to be believed.  It seems that the enacting of various titles as "positive law" began in 1947.  Congress simply hasn't "gotten around to" enacting all the titles; I do not know whether they presently have any plans to do the remaining titles.
